# Laravel 5.3 determine redirection based on factors

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I realize that I can change where my user is directed after login by changing

```
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

in the LoginController.php

However, I want to check if there are any items in a shopping cart and if so, direct the user to the checkout page. I may also check to see if they have purchased a service that is active and direct them to the dashboard, then anyone else to the homepage.

Anyone know how to apply some logic to the redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `sendLoginResponse()` method in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php` to perform the check and redirect to whatever route you want.

Original `sendLoginResponse()` method is in [`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L86). Copy-paste it to `LoginController.php` and then work with it. Do not change anything in an original trait.

Comment: This is working well, thanks! What about a failed login attempt? I'm trying to add #login to the return URL (goes back to my checkout page) but I need to open the login tab (bootstrap)